# Retrieving name of the service which is running behind the svchost

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Is it possible to know the details about the service (name, description, version etc), which is running behind the svchost.exe by process id in C/C++?

Currently I'm going to get list of the running system services and compare their PIDs with the PID of the svchost.exe, which I already have. But I'm not completely sure, that there is no better solution for such kind of task.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Richie

Comment: I'm kind of worried what you're going to do with this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you will have to compare PIDs.  Use `EnumServiceStatusEx()` to get the PID of each running service.  Just know that it is possible for multiple services to share the same process if they were implemented in the same executable and have the `SERVICE_WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS` flag enabled, so you might sometimes encounter multiple hits.

Comment: Thanks for reply, Remy. Probably, I'll act in such way.